# Fabric and cygwin don't work with windows UNC paths

Tags: cygwin, windows-server-2008-r2

I have some strange problems with fabric deployment to Windows Server 2008r2.

The thing I try to accomplish is to copy some files to a shared folder with a fabric script (this script does a lot of other things too, but only this step gives me problems).

**This is the problem:**

When I try to access a UNC(Universal Naming convention) path I always get access denied kind of answers if I run the script in fabric. When I run the command in an ssh prompt (same user) it works fine.

**Examples:**

- *cmd:* robocopy f:/.... //share

  - *result:* in ssh this works fine, in fabric I get "Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type aat this computer."
- *cmd:* cd //share

  - *result:* in ssh this works fine, in fabric I get "//share: Not a directory"

**Further information:**

uname -a and whoami return exact the same thing in fabric and ssh.

I also tried things like *mount*, *net use*, but these commands all have kind of the same problem.